# No live threads left. Deadlock?

Tags: ruby, celluloid

I have a set of workers `MessageConsumer`, each with different responsibilities: HTTP calls, CRUD Mongo/Redis, API calls etc.

They have the same structure:

```
class MessageConsumer
  include Celluloid

  def perform(sqs_message)
    # Do something
  end
end
```

And I have a file `[worker-name].rb` for each worker with something like that:

```
Celluloid::Actor[:pool] = MessageConsumer.pool

while @still_running
  sqs_message =  @queue.receive_message(start_options)

  if sqs_message
    Celluloid::Actor[:pool].async.perform(sqs_message)
  else
    # sleep for a while as there's nothing in the queue.
    sleep rand(2..6)
  end
end
```

The `@queue.receive_message` receives a message from Amazon SQS and call the worker passing the message.

In each server we have a set of `[worker-name].rb` running:

```
pgrep -fl ruby

14885 ruby bin/worker_http # two processes
15890 ruby bin/worker_http # ^^^
17956 ruby bin/worker_api
19734 ruby bin/worker_mongo
22637 ruby bin/worker_redis
```

The problem: I'm getting`"No live threads left. Deadlock?"` frequently after running the processes for a while (after getting threads busy).

I'm using `ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [x86_64-linux]` in the servers, not sure if it's a problem related to MRI, maybe I need to switch to JRuby. But interesting I don't see this issue very common, so I think it might be a problem with my implementation.

Any ideas?

Comment: your threads hit an error and all die? Or at some point all threads are busy and none are ready to accept the task? These are just some guesses because never used `Celluloid::Actor`.

Comment: > Or at some point all threads are busy - Correct, they get busy and I get the error, not all the time, but frequently. I'm asking it, because I thought Celluloid has a fault tolerance for that, so might be a problem in my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like adding of limit to join would resolve this problem:

```
     [1] pry(main)> task = Thread.new { Thread.stop }
     => #<Thread:0x000055918c669018@(pry):1 sleep_forever>
     [2] pry(main)> task.join
     fatal: No live threads left. Deadlock?
     2 threads, 2 sleeps current:0x000055918bc08ef0 main thread:0x000055918bc08ef0
     * #<Thread:0x000055918bc3cbf8 sleep_forever>
        rb_thread_t:0x000055918bc08ef0 native:0x00007efd46186080 int:0
        (pry):2:in `join'
        (pry):2:in `__pry__'
        /home/mifrill/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:355:in `eval'
        /home/mifrill/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:355:in `evaluate_ruby'
        /home/mifrill/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:323:in `handle_line'
        /home/mifrill/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:243:in `block (2 levels) in eval'
        /home/mifrill/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:242:in `catch'
        /home/mifrill/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:242:in `block in eval'
        /home/mifrill/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:241:in `catch'
        /home/mifrill/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/pry_instance.rb:241:in `eval'
        /home/mifrill/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/repl.rb:77:in `block in repl'
        /home/mifrill/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `loop'
        /home/mifrill/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/repl.rb:67:in `repl'
        /home/mifrill/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `block in start'
        /home/mifrill/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:61:in `__with_ownership'
        /home/mifrill/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/input_lock.rb:79:in `with_ownership'
        /home/mifrill/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/repl.rb:38:in `start'
        /home/mifrill/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/repl.rb:13:in `start'
        /home/mifrill/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/pry_class.rb:192:in `start'
        /home/mifrill/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/lib/pry/cli.rb:116:in `start'
        /home/mifrill/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pry-0.11.3/bin/pry:12:in `<top (required)>'
        /home/mifrill/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/pry:23:in `load'
        /home/mifrill/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/pry:23:in `<main>'
     * #<Thread:0x000055918c669018@(pry):1 sleep_forever>
        rb_thread_t:0x000055918c742dd0 native:0x00007efd4377e700 int:0
         depended by: tb_thread_id:0x000055918bc08ef0
        (pry):1:in `stop'
        (pry):1:in `block in __pry__'
     from (pry):2:in `join'
     [3] pry(main)> task.join 1
     => nil
```

try to increase it inside lib/celluloid/actor.rb:

```
  def join(actor, timeout = nil)
    actor.thread.join(timeout)
    actor
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a not a (final) answer to the question, but maybe helps others coming in here, to understand their Problem.

Just add a `Thread.new { sleep }` to your source.

**This does not solve the problem!**

It just helps - sometimes - to get error messages after the 'bad thing' happened.

Because "Deadlock?" is just a suggestion and in many cases it is a "Dead end", so there are errors following, that point to the real cause, that you don't see, because Ruby takes the emergency trip wire.

With a - useless - `Thread` alive, Ruby does not, exit so fast.

**And again:** this is not a solution. Just a debugging help.